# How to get grid cell value before update

Tags: c#, database, validation, datagridview, cell

What is the best way to get datagridviw cell value just before update of that cell? On every update of certain column cell in datagridview, I need to make some changes in database, based on values before and after update.
What is the best way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `CellEndEdit` event ?

```
private void yourGrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {

    string value = yourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

on click of particular cell, you can save its value in temparary variable before updation.

Syntax as follows:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     valBeforeUpdate=dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This I can use for before update value. That seemed to me harder to get. Thanks for idea!